# Replace occurrences of " [any number]" with "[number]" in UNIX

Tags: regex

i have entries in my file like

```
abcd abcd [23]
shbfh sfklgh [47]
sdgnjsfgj [45]
```

I want to change it to

```
abcd abcd[23]
shbfh sfklgh[47]
sdgnjsfgj[45]
```

I tried `sed 's/ \[[0-9]+\]/\[[0-9]+\]/g'` , but it isn't working

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture the group, and use a backreference to it in replacement:

```
sed 's/ \(\[[0-9]\+\]\)/\1/g'
```

Comment: Your command results in `sed: -e expression #1, char 20: invalid reference \1 on s command's RHS`. You need to escape the braces and the plus sign. Like this: `sed 's/ \(\[[0-9]\+\]\)/\1/g'`

Comment: @erik. Does it happen like that in sed? I don't know.

Comment: @erik. In that case, wouldn't `\[` and `\]` create a character class around - `[0-9]\+`? If we go by consistency?

Comment: Well, no. It only works like I said. I can even do `sed 's/ \([[0-9]\+]\)/\1/g'` without escaping the [] braces and it still works! I have GNU sed version 4.2.1. Which sed are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the space before any square bracket using something like this if this will be the only occurrence of a square bracket:

```
sed 's/ \[/\[/'
```